# Semaphore with different user does not work

Tags: c, semaphore

I am working a c- project which uses semaphores to handle the same function at the same time. When I run it, on linux, under the root user, it works perfect. But if I run it on another user, the script isn't executed and it leaves a semaphore in the semaphore array. Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argC, char* argv[]) {

    pthread_t thr[argC-1];
    int indexes[argC-1];
    int i,j;
    for(j=0; j<(argC-1); j++) {

        indexes[j] = atoi(argv[j+1]);
        pthread_create (&thr[j], NULL, (int *) &stabtest, (void *) &indexes[j]);  
    }

    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1); 

    for(j=0; j<(argC-1); j++) pthread_join(thr[j], NULL);

    // Destroy semaphore
    sem_destroy(&mutex);

    // Exit
    exit(0);   
}

int stabtest(void *ptr) {

    sem_wait(&mutex); // down semaphore

    // Other code ...

    sem_post(&mutex); // up semaphore 
    pthread_exit(0);  // exit thread 

}
```

This code I actually found on the internet because I have no experience with semaphores. So I am not sure of this code is the right one to run the function in parallel at the same time. But it works for the root user, so I guess the code is more or less ok.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the code you are using, whatever you think is happening isn't happening.  Permissions should have no effect on the semaphore you are using.  And there is no semaphore array, you are using a single semaphore.

You seem to have a shaky grasp on command line parms.  They are an array pointers to string.  argc is the number of arguments.  There will always be at least 1 argv, argv[0], which is the program name.  Please don't rename argc.  Everyone knows what argc is.  Renaming it will just annoy people.

You start your threads and *then* you initialize your semaphore.  That's a problem.

The start function of a pthread *has* to have the signature `void* stabtest(void *ptr)`.  Yours is `int stabtest(void *ptr)` and you are trying to cast your way out of a mistake.  Don't do that.  If you want to return something from a thread you do it through the void ptr used as the 4th parm in `pthread_create`.  That is, allocate some memory, pass it in pthread_create, do whatever you need to in the thread to change the information pointed to, and then return the same void ptr from the thread.  When you do your `pthread_join` you can access the returned pointer to the data in the second paramater in `pthread_join`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t mutex;

void* stabtest(void *ptr)
{
    sem_wait(&mutex); // down semaphore
    printf("in thread %lu...\n", pthread_self());
    sem_post(&mutex); // up semaphore

    pthread_exit(0);  // exit thread
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: %s numThread\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    int maxThreads = atoi(argv[1]);

    pthread_t thr[maxThreads];
    int indexes[maxThreads];
    int i, j;

    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

    for (j = 0; j < maxThreads; j++)
        pthread_create (&thr[j], NULL, stabtest, NULL);

    for (j = 0; j < maxThreads; j++)
        pthread_join(thr[j], NULL);

    // Destroy semaphore
    sem_destroy(&mutex);

    // Exit
    exit(0);
}
```